How can I use excel functions to identify whether an enter date is a holiday?

Hi,
I have a dataset that includes all weekdays, displayed in blue, and another dataset containing holidays from 2024 to 2026, shown in green. I would like to identify which dates in the weekdays table are holidays and display the results as "True" or "False" in a column labeled "HLDAY," based on the holiday data.
I’ve tried using VLOOKUP and XLOOKUP, but they didn’t work as expected. Could you please show me how to solve this using Excel functions?

Try =ISNUMBER(XMATCH([@DATE],TOCOL(Holidays[[2024]:[2026]],3))).

Add all your holidays to a single column - you can easily filter by year and you won't have to update your formula when you add 2027 holidays.

If there are no extra columns in the Holidays table, you could improve (make it more dynamic) with =ISNUMBER(XMATCH([@DATE],TOCOL(DROP(Holidays,,1),3))).

With 365 CHOOSECOLS function select the relevant column of the date like this:
Cell references see on the attached sheet screenshot.
=LET(year,YEAR(B2),
col,MATCH(year,$G$1:$I$1,0),
res,VLOOKUP(B2,CHOOSECOLS($G$1:$I$13,col),1,FALSE),
IF(ISERROR(res),"NO","YES"))



In blue C2 use formula
=Not(And(IsNA(match(B2, Green!$B$2:Green!$B$13,0))
      ,And(IsNA(match(B2, Green!$C$2:Green!$C$13,0))
          ,IsNA(match(B2, Green!$D$2:Green!$D$13,0))
       )))

Unfortunately, none of the lookup\match functions in Excel look up in 2 dimensions. This looks them all up individually by column.
Filling the formula down will propagate it to all the individual blue values.
